# How to write own video service?

Tags: python-3.x, video-streaming

I need to write own video hosting with player on client side.

**My required approaches:**

- The user can upload video to hosting
- The user can watch any video from hosting

I don't ask to write me solution, I am asking for help where should I start from to lean about it? Which technologies or frameworks should I learn for my task to realize it using python?
**P.S.** Each detail will be very useful, especially some links to articles because I couldn't find by myself not knowing accurately what do I need to search.
**Added**
Now, I think to store videos in the file system directly and use postgresql to store additional information about videos and users.  Of course, large services use Hadoop, BigTable and etc but for my task so solution will be enough I think.
When the user uploaded a new video, my server saves it into a temporary directory and puts in the processing queue. Small programs takes new videos one by one, generates thumbnails and decrease a quality of videos and moves it to the base storage. Is it a good idea?
But I still can't get how make a video streaming

Comment: oops, didnt see ur edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I dont want to encourage the behavior of people thinking SO is a codewriting service, But this is a truly legitimate answer. So first of all, you want to choose a language. Currently I'd recommend the use of `javascript` and  `Node.js` (`Java` needs to die). However, IDK Node as well as I know Python. `Python` is an all purpose language yadda yadda yadda blah blah blah. Whats important in this case is your framework of choice  (or library). The libraries that allow you to make websites in python (or make it easier to do so) are very interesting. There are several but my favorite is Python `Flask`. `Python flask` is actually very similar to Node.js + Express.js. Use this [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) to get started. Take a few days to learn the insides of this framework. VERY MODULAR, VERY POWERFUL. Using basing logic and database knowledge, one can easily accomplish a simple file upload and authentication-using, web service. However I Know of 2 really good guides that will help you with the streaming of the videos. I mean yes, You don't *really* need to know this. You could potentially load the requested video using a `<video>` tag, but streaming is a much **MUCH**
 more favorable solution. Take some time to learn about video streaming and compression, and after you think about it, check out these links: [AUDIO STREAMING GIST](https://gist.github.com/hosackm/289814198f43976aff9b) and [MIGUEL GRINBERG FLASK VIDEO STREAMING BLOG POST](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

Good luck with flask and
Pro tip: learn about http(s) and the get and post methods
You would never imagine how many times I struggled with a `bad request error` or a `method not allowed` because I didn't do my research

Comment: please mark my answer as answered, so I know that I have Answered your question :D